# Visualforce <Apex:tabpanel> breaks MathJax (math formating script)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-debugging

Problem:
I am using [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format math equations nicely on a visualforce page.

Everything goes great on a naked vf page.

[image]

```
<apex:page >
<!--script id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script-->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$resource.mathjax}"/>
    <p>
        \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
    </p>
</apex:page>
```

(both the static resource and html script tags work)

**BUT**

When I add an apex:tabpanel to the page, the formating disapears.

[image]

I know that [tabpanel](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205528) has issues playing nice with jquery. So in a rough stab in the dark, I implemented a similar fix that sfdc outlined in the linked post.

```
<apex:page >
<!--script id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script-->
<apex:includeScript id ="mathjax" value="{!$resource.mathjax}"/>
<script>
mathjax.noConflict();
</script>
    <p>
        \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
    </p>
<apex:tabPanel></apex:tabPanel>
```

This did nothing so I checked out the chrome js console and found this:
[image]

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent' of undefined
at a (mathjax:1)
at u (mathjax:1)
at _ (mathjax:1)
at A (mathjax:1)
at new <anonymous> (3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript:17)
at Object.node.<computed> [as text] (mathjax:1)
at l.c.create (mathjax:1)
at r.I.compileError (mathjax:1)
at Object.compileError (mathjax:1)
at r.I.compileMath (mathjax:1)
```

Anyone ever seen something like this?/know how to repair it.

**EDIT**

Followed the bouncing ball a bit further:
In the JS console I found the following when I clicked on the link of mathjax:1 in the error readout.  I believe parent is getting unset when I add tabpanel to the page.

Does anyone know how to re-set or maybe prevent it from going to null?

[image]

Comment: use [edit] to include the error message so it gets more eyeballs

Comment: @cropredy Morning! I added the picture. Should I add the error to the title? or it in plain text in the body?

Comment: The first error shows that mathjax is not defined. Can you check the source listed there to see where that is coming from? It mentions apexpa.., so I don't know if that is coming from Salesforce, or mathjax, but it seems like the variable is getting unset or something like that.

Comment: you might also get some help from stackoverflow where there are many more jQuery experts

Comment: I followed Roti's advice, If that scenario means anything Let me know, Im, going to do some research on it before cross-posting.

Comment: Did you also try clicking the first error's link? I"m not sure what mathTest is, but I'm guessing that it is part of tabPanel  and it may have a variable in there named mathjax. Of course, this is just a wild guess.